# Is there a circumstance where you will rebase your local repo and then push instead of push force?

Tags: git, push, rebase

My company is working to transition into using Git and we are currently working on the workflow. After rebasing a feature branch onto master, would you always use

```
git push origin feature-branch -f
```

or is there a circumstance where

```
git push
```

is sufficient? We are attempting to understand rebasing and how pushing versus force pushing changes the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a circumstance.  Suppose you were working on some `feature` branch, derived from `master`.  And let's say you made some number of commits, and were ready to push to the repo and create a pull request.  You most likely would want to sync up with `master` before you push.  One way of doing this would be via a rebase pull:

```
# from feature
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Now, all your commits in the `feature` branch are sitting on top of the latest `master` base.  Because you have not yet pushed `feature`, you do not need the `--force` option:

```
# create new remote branch
git push origin feature
```

Comment: We're working with Git within MS Visual Studio. Would a pull, then rebase be equivalent to the "git pull --rebase origin master" you stated above?

Comment: No, it probably would not be the same.  Basically, there are two pull strategies in Git.  One is `git pull`, short for `git pull --merge`.  This is the default strategy, and it creates a merge commit (unless a fast forward can be done).  The alternative is `git pull --rebase`, which rebases your local branch on its remote counterpart.  Long winded comment, but you need to turn on rebase pull in your VS Git plugin.